# Notepad++ search and replace after the search word

Tags: replace, notepad++

Good Day

I need to replace all words that happens after the search word with the specific set of text in notepad++. I have 980 instances of this to change. I will put three instances in this and show how do they need to change. The search word I will use is `"readDataGroup"`

Example
Current Data:

1. `readDataGroup="E_READ_Total_WPC"`
2. `readDataGroup="E_READ_Total_WSI"`
3. `readDataGroup="E_READ_Total_WSP"`

Transformed Data:

1. `readDataGroup="Everyone"`
2. `readDataGroup="Everyone"`
3. `readDataGroup="Everyone"`

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated
Rehaan

I have tried using Regex but I have not succeeded as I am not too familiar with regex

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\breadDataGroup="\K[^"]+`
- Replace with: `Everyone`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b                  # word boundary
readDataGroup="     # literally
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
[^"]+               # 1 or more any character that is not double quote
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]